# Remove duplicate record based on certain fields in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to remove duplicates from Inputfile.txt. Duplicate logic applies based on certain fields. For instance, **911548.PP.K** contains these fields as duplicate **5319,4790,10/03/2017** - it has three record out of three we need to remove which will have lower date on last field. As per this record 10/04/2017 need to be removed and keep the greater date. In this case 911548.PP.K has two record with same greater date so pick either one.

I've other scenario which is failing with below script, this key has 154610.PP.K two record but the fields we are checking duplicate its different. For instance:

```
154610 5643,1293,10/03/2017 and
154610 9835,83932,10/03/2017
```

In this case it should remove the record, since duplicate fields are not matching, so these key not consider as duplicate record.

But below shell command is considering this also duplicate record, how to fix this?

```
awk -F ' |,' '{t=$NF;gsub("/","",t);if(b[$1]<t){a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=t}}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' inputfile.txt
```

**Inputfile.txt**

```
194365.PP.K 06ae6a319ec8,7012,3692,10/03/2017,7,Q,MM,f9cd8.csv,4754454,csv,,405a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
911548.PP.K 876d4108-b08,5319,4790,10/03/2017,7,Q,NN,g8ijk.csv,4754454,csv,,e9051.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
154610.PP.K 9c9d9d2a-j9k,5643,1293,10/03/2017,7,Q,PP,6001j.csv,4754454,csv,,907a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
223410.PP.K ab16e77a-09j,8403,43011,10/03/2017,7,Q,OO,f2cd.csv,4754454,csv,,a97ai.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
234173.PP.K fa180bd-81d3,4608,4697,10/03/2017,7,Q,EC,0015d8.csv,4754454,csv,,we405.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
911548.PP.K 876d4108-b08,5319,4790,10/03/2017,7,Q,NN,g8ijk.csv,4754454,csv,,e9051.csv,4,25139,txt,10/05/2017
911548.PP.K 876d4108-b08,5319,4790,10/03/2017,7,Q,NN,g8ijk.csv,4754454,csv,,e9051.csv,4,25139,txt,10/05/2017
154610.PP.K 9c9d9d2a-j9k,9835,83932,10/03/2017,7,Q,PP,6001j.csv,4754454,csv,,907a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
```

**OutputFile.txt**

```
194365.PP.K 06ae6a319ec8,7012,3692,10/03/2017,7,Q,MM,f9cd8.csv,4754454,csv,,405a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
154610.PP.K 9c9d9d2a-j9k,5643,1293,10/03/2017,7,Q,PP,6001j.csv,4754454,csv,,907a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
223410.PP.K ab16e77a-09j,8403,43011,10/03/2017,7,Q,OO,f2cd.csv,4754454,csv,,a97ai.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
234173.PP.K fa180bd-81d3,4608,4697,10/03/2017,7,Q,EC,0015d8.csv,4754454,csv,,we405.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
911548.PP.K 876d4108-b08,5319,4790,10/03/2017,7,Q,NN,g8ijk.csv,4754454,csv,,e9051.csv,4,25139,txt,10/05/2017
154610.PP.K 9c9d9d2a-j9k,9835,83932,10/03/2017,7,Q,PP,6001j.csv,4754454,csv,,907a1.csv,4,25139,txt,10/04/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multi dimensional arrays in awk

```
    awk -F \, '{rec[$2,$3,$4]=$0} END{for(k in rec){print(rec[k]}}' input.file
```

This will goof-up the order of lines.  Is there a key you can re-sort the output with?

Comment: All these are key only 194365.PP.K